# How to set the id field when submitting multiple objects in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am creating many new objects of a model (RecurringPayments) with a Rails view. The source of the data is an array of hashes in the @transactions variable.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <%= form_with(url: recurring_payments_path, local: true) do |form| %>
    <% @transactions.each.with_index do |t, i| %>
      <tr>
        <%= fields_for 'recurring_payments[]', t do |rp| %>
          <td><%= check_box_tag :selected %></td>
          <td><%= t[:name] %><%= rp.hidden_field :name, value: t[:name] %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>

    <%= submit_tag 'Continue' %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

This code actually works, and submits a hash of key => value pairs. The keys are unique and the values are the values in each form.

The problem is that the id of each input is the concatenation of the key value pairs of each transaction:

```
"name=Transaction1&..."
```

How can I set the id of each form?

Googling showed passing `html: { id: i }` would work, but it does not appear to do anything.

```
fields_for 'recurring_payments[]', t, html: { id: i } do |rp|
```

Rails 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I set the id of each form?

You can't. `fields_for` does not generate forms - in fact it does not actually generate any HTML on its own.

Nested form elements are not permitted by any of the HTML standards.
`fields_for` simply nests inputs through the name attribute.

If you want the resulting params to be a hash you want to add the index to the name attribute:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <%= form_with(url: recurring_payments_path, local: true) do |form| %>
    <% @transactions.each.with_index do |t, i| %>
      <tr>
        <%= fields_for "recurring_payments[#{i}]", t do |rp| %>
          <td><%= check_box_tag :selected %></td>
          <td><%= t[:name] %><%= rp.hidden_field :name, value: t[:name] %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>

    <%= submit_tag 'Continue' %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

> The problem is that the id of each input is the concatenation of the
>   key value pairs of each transaction ...

You can use [CGI.escape](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI/Util.html) to escape the sequence so that it can be passed as a formdata parameter:

```
>> CGI.escape("foo=bar&baz=2")
=> "foo%3Dbar%26baz%3D2"
```

`CGI.unescape` can be used on the other end to unpack the values. You can also use [Base64.urlsafe_encode64](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-urlsafe_encode64).

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!